# splitting docker stdout and stderr with fluentd fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter plugin

Tags: docker, fluentd

I currently have the following config:

```
<match docker.nginx>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  rewriterule1 source stdout docker.nginx.stdout
  rewriterule2 source stderr docker.nginx.stderr
</match>
```

but this means, that with each container I have to do the same.
This isn't working, but probably you'll get what I want from it:

```
<match docker.*>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  rewriterule1 source stdout docker.*.stdout
  rewriterule2 source stdout docker.*.stderr
</match>
```

So my question is can I somehow refer to the matched tag in the match block? So if it's nginx/rabbitmq/zookeeper/anything, it will split all event flows into `docker.<fluentd-tag>.stdout` and stderr.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any luck on this in the meantime?

Comment: nah, sorry :(. What I've seen how kubernetes does the splitting is to send the log entries into files and then fluentd parsing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Fluentd record_transformer parameter](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer#parameters) , you could try and use placeholders to refer to captured patterns in the tag, applying dynamic transformations based on those captured values.

For your requirement, you would use a wildcard (`*`) to capture the tag and then refer to that captured value using a placeholder (`${tag_parts[N]}`) in the `rewrite_tag_filter` plugin.

```xml
<match docker.*>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  rewriterule1 source stdout docker.${tag_parts[1]}.stdout
  rewriterule2 source stderr docker.${tag_parts[1]}.stderr
</match>
```

In this case, `${tag_parts[1]}` would refer to the part of the tag after `docker.` (e.g., `nginx`, `rabbitmq`, `zookeeper`, etc.).

Any tag that matches the pattern `docker.*` will have its events rewritten based on the source (either `stdout` or `stderr`) to tags like `docker.nginx.stdout`, `docker.rabbitmq.stderr`, and so on.